# Converting existing .csproj to .shproj

Tags: visual-studio

What's the best approach to convert existing `.csproj`s to the new `.shproj`s?

I'm currently finding myself in git submodule hell, as I have something like this:

```
- A
    - B
        - C
            - D
    - E
    - F
```

Libraries `C` and `D` are both referenced in `A`, as well as `B`, `E` and `F`. `B` is a separate entity, and needs to reference `C`, hence `C` is a submodule in `B`. It's the same relationship for `C` and `D`.

When I need to update `D`, I have to update `C` and then `B` before I can finally commit the changes in `A`, which is becoming rather tedious. `A` is my `.sln`, and all other letters are really other `.sln`s added via submodules.

I wanted to convert my existing class libraries (`.csproj`s) to shared projects to mitigate this issue, but the best way I currently know is:

- Renaming existing project so it doesn't conflict with the new shared project
- Add new shared project.
- Copy across all the original classes.

That's rather tedious. Is there a better way?

Or am I only in this predicament because `A` should really have it's own copy of `C` and `D`?